# How to remove name of parent directory in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am passing a file path to a method. An example is the following:
The method--

```py
def example(image):
     code not shown
```

The call to the method--

```py
example("resources/1.png")
```

In this, I want to remove the "resources/" part using the example method and simply return "1.png". How can I do that?

Comment: Why is the "code not shown", please show us the code

Comment: Are you looking for the `os.path.basename` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library has exactly the function you're looking for, it's called [basename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename). you just need to import `os`:

```
>>> import os                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
>>> os.path.basename("resources/1.png")                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
'1.png'
```

I guess your function could then be written as:

```
from os import path  # Usually goes at the top of the file

def example(image):
    return path.basename(image)
```